# Enterprise Architect not a valid name

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm now using Enterprise Architect version 15. Recently, whenever I try to create a new project I got the error show that "Not a valid file name":

[image]

Although, my file name is not wrong, I've tried many difference names but it's useless. Now, I just able to open the projects which I've create before.
Can anyone help me how to fix this error.

Comment: How are you trying to create the new project?

Comment: I click "Create new project", then select the place where this file will be save and named this file. But all names are useless. I checked the folder and saw the project with that named has been created but I cant open it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've just found the answer. That could be the program's fault.
The issue here isn't the way I named the project. It's because the folder where I decided  the project located. The folder is named in Vietnamese (which is allowed in Windows) but I guess EA can't read these character when they get the project located link.

In conclusion, It's better for everyone to name not only the project but also the folder the project located in English to prevent this error

Comment: What does that mean: not valid in EA? Could you elaborate?

Comment: I named the prj in Vietnamese language and I guess EA don't allow that

Comment: You should state that in your answer. It might be helpful then. And you can remove the "silly me". That's clearly the tools fault here.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I very appreciate that. I will edit my answer to make it more clearly

Comment: You might as well send a bug report to Sparx. Though there's not such a big hope to see a fix for that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with trying to save the file image. I found that when I originally created the Diagram name I unknowingly pasted in as 2 lines.
Once I fixed it as one line it saved fine.